# frequent error 6398 6482 generated in Event log for WSS 3

Tags: wss-3.0, error

We currently have a stand alone instance of WSS 3 on Windows 2003.  We are seeing a repeated error in the Event Log.  The Event ID is 6398 and 6482 and is saturating the app log.  It appears Hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946517 might resolve but want to exhaust easier options without introducing the hotfix to the environment.

Event Type: Error
Event Source: Windows SharePoint Services 3
Event Category: Timer
Event ID: 6398
Date:  02/20/07
Time:  11:01:41 PM
User:  N/A
Computer: WGE
Description:
The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerAdministrationServiceJob (ID de82c7d5-76d8-4c54-81bc-2dd35824b0b8) threw an exception. More information is included below.

The path specified cannot be used at this time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070094)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
`

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, that was something about IIS, Search service and accounts for them. Hotfix helped us, but try this links to see more

http://sharemypoint.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/error-event-id-6398-and-6482-about-security-rights-of-osearch-service/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/e8b34a19-c9d4-49ae-9015-33f9c0eedf3d/   (Find the answer from SharePoint_007 user)